# Showing that sequence of component-wise convergent sequences converges with an additional boundedness assumption

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose that $(x^{(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of sequences of complex numbers that is bounded in the following sense: there exists $M>0$ such that
>
> $$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^2|x_j^{(n)}|^2 \leq M$$
>
> for all $n$. Show that $(x^{(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ has a convergent subsequence that converges in $\ell^2$.

So I used a diagonal argument to obtain a subsequence $(x^{(n_j)})_{j=1}^\infty$ that converges component-wise, but I need to show the subsequence converges in $\ell^2$. Of course it doesn't necessarily without the boundedness condition so somehow I have to use this. However I have tried and can't seem to use it correctly to show convergence of the sequences. I've tried with the definition $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k^{(n_j)}-y_k|^2 \to \infty$ as $j \to \infty$ (where the $y_k$ are the component-wise limits) as well as trying to show $(x^{(n_j)})_{j=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $\ell^2$ but I couldn't make progress. Perhaps it uses the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but I couldn't use that in a meaningful way either. Hints, but not full solutions, would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about "relative compactness" in $\ell^2$?

Comment: I don't think so. But this is a problem in a Functional Analysis module so I am aware of some concepts and theorems in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define

$$E=\{x\in l^2: \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^2|x_j|^2 \leq M\}.$$

You'll be done if you show that if $(y^{(n})$ is a sequence in $E$ that converges to $y$ in each component, then $y^{(n)}\to y$ in $l^2.$ To do this observe

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|y_j^{(n)}-y_j|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{J}|y_j^{(n)}-y_j|^2 + \sum_{j=J+1}^{\infty}\frac{4M}{j^2}.$$

Comment: The notation here seems slightly incorrect because we should be talking about the subsequence $x^{(n_j)}$, but I think I get the idea. In my notation it seems we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k^{(n_j)}-y_k|^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^N |x_k^{(n_j)}-y_k|^2 +\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{4M^2}{k^2}$. Then it is clear how to proceed from here. But I feel uneasy about this because I only used the fact that each term in the sum bounded by $M$ is bounded by $M$, not the whole sum. Is this inequality correct?

Comment: I"m not sure what your question is. I edited my answer; perhaps that will help.

Comment: I was simply asking if the inequality I stated was correct (using my notation). I suppose the best way to clarify here is to ask how you got the bound $\frac{4M}{j^2}$. When I do it I get an $M^2$ instead of an $M$.

Comment: I don't know. I'm using

$$|y_j^{(n)}-y_j|^2 \le (|y_j^{(n)}|+|y_j|)^2 \le (\sqrt M/j+\sqrt M/j)^2 = 4M^2/j^2.$$

Comment: Correction: that should be $4M/j^2$

Comment: Actually that seems correct, I made a silly computational mistake there. The main thing is the idea with splitting the sum so that you can take limits of the terms of the finite sum, which was helpful. But I still think it's weird that we can get away with only using the fact the terms in your set $E$ are bounded by $M$ and not the full series themselves.

Comment: The hypotheses do seem unnecessarily strong.